# Imu_attitude_to_tf_node Error: 'command not found'

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to convert data from the Pixhawk IMU to a transform broadcast using the "hector_imu_attitude_to_tf" node from the Hector SLAM repository (found at:
[link text](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/melodic-devel/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp) )
However, when I run the file using:

```
rosrun hector_imu_attitude_to_tf imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp
```

I get the following error message, with "command not found" listed 5 times, as well as 2 other errors:

```
/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 5: std::string: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 6: std::string: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 7: tf::TransformBroadcaster*: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 8: tf::StampedTransform: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 9: tf::Quaternion: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 12: typedef: command not found
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/home/luengr/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf/src/imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp: line 13: `  namespace tf { typedef btMatrix3x3 Matrix3x3; }'
```

It has been suggested to me that this is a dependencies issue, however i have used Rosdep to install all dependencies with no luck. Is there something I am not seeing? I assume it is something I have not set up properly as I assume the code from the Hector-SLAM repository is working fine.
Many Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345164/imu_attitude_to_tf_node-error:-%27command-not-found%27/) by [SamH](https://answers.ros.org/users/51432/samh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, when I run the file using:

> ```
> rosrun hector_imu_attitude_to_tf imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp
> ```

you cannot directly execute `.cpp` files.

C++ is a compiled language, so you need to first build the package and only then can you start the node(s).

Did you run `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) before trying to start anything?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SamH](https://answers.ros.org/users/51432/samh/) on 2020-02-27**:
That explains a lot!
How do I build the package and start the node? I did run catkin_make, and also used "chmod +x imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp" to give the file execution rights.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-27**:
These appear to be questions that would have been answered by the [introductory tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages). In short: `cd` to the root of your workspace and then run `catkin_make` (after having run `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`).

> and also used "chmod +x imu_attitude_to_tf_node.cpp" to give the file execution rights.

No. That's not how this works.

This is C++, not Python or a shell script.

**Comment by [SamH](https://answers.ros.org/users/51432/samh/) on 2020-02-28**:
I'm afraid I'm not familiar with running C++ files so thank you for your explanation. I have now resolved the issue. Thanks again